# Where is the right correct for this prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

1. The man is wearing a scarf in the shop.
   2  The man in the shop is wearing a scarf.

The prepositional phrase is placed after the verb in (1) and after the noun in (2), so would you please help me to explain the difference between two sentences? and which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct. There are no grammatical errors. They basically mean the same. It's just that No.1 emphasises the wearing of the scarf, and No.2 emphasises his location.

Answer (score 1):

(2) is the most natural; it tells us that a certain man (the one who is in the shop) is wearing a scarf.

The order of words in (1) emphasises the place where he is wearing it (perhaps suggesting that it's unusual to wear a scarf indoors). Compare "I don't wear my spectacles in bed."